# Nothing happens after account chooser while sign in google from Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I have implemented the google sign_in package but after the account has been choosen, a white page appears with a loading icon and nothing happens. And even I stop the app in the emulator, the white page remains in the emulator. Both in AVD and real device.

```
void sendingTestEmail() async {
await googleSignIn.signIn().then((data) {
  data.authHeaders.then((result) async {
    
    
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Maybe the app hasn’t got network permission?

Comment: ALthought it was missing (thank you), the problem is the same.